# Alias Column Names at the Database Level [MySQL]

Tags: mysql, sql

"Alias" is probably the wrong word, since that's used in the context of referencing column/table names as something else in a Query.

What I'm interested in is if there's a way to give a column two names in the database. If I were to print such a table, it would look like this:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM User;
+--------------------------+-----------------+
| id | username | uname    | password | pswd |
+----+---------------------+-----------------+
|  0 | bob_jones@gmail.com |    some_pw_hash | 
|  1 | sue_smith@gmail.com |    some_pw_hash |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

In this case, `username` and `uname` would be synonymous in query statements, as would `password` and `pswd`.

So the following statements would have the same output:

```
mysql> SELECT id, username FROM User;
...
mysql> SELECT id, uname FROM User;
...
```

I would like to avoid having to do something like

```
mysql> SELECT id, username AS uname FROM User;
```

So, does a feature like this exist?

Cheers,
Neil

Comment: Well shucks. Thanks :)

Comment: This is possible, fsvo, if using *Views*.

Comment: @user2864740 Using a `VIEW` does not do what the poster is asking; you'd have to `SELECT` from the `VIEW` instead of the table, which means it wouldn't do what the poster is asking to do with his SQL statements.

Comment: @user2864740: You're not reading the question. The poster wants to do it **WITHOUT** changing the table name in the `SELECT`. Read the last two code samples (and the text that is with them) in the question again.

Comment: I know *exactly* what a view is; I'm not exactly new to them. You're clearly not understanding the actual question being asked. :-)

Comment: ___why___ do you want to do this?  there might be a good alternative...

Comment: Certainly a view doesn't do *precisely* what was requested. But given that he needs to write new SQL, it seems possible that a view would be a useful piece to get there.

Comment: @user2864740: I'm not going to continue debating this with you. :-) If you want to keep discussing it, go ahead.

Comment: @mdahlman: That's **not what the poster asked**. See the last two code samples the poster included, as I've said before. The question asks about giving the column **two names at the database level**, and that is NOT possible.

Comment: @user623952 It was more of a curiosity than an actual desire.

Comment: why, though.... can't you just use naming conventions and make everything the expected name...?  I don't understand why you would need something like this... a column having two names essentially.  why?

Comment: i dunno...  a view is it, i think.  with sql server you could do a computed column.  make a view with every possible name mutation... `select username, username as user_name, username as uname, username as u_name, username as usrnm, username as user from Users` and then you could just use whatever at random.  and do the same for user_id,  user_password, and every other table attribute.  even include misspellings for the sake of it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is not possible.  To do so, you'd have to add a new, actual second column and use triggers to keep them in sync, which would be silly.

Just write your SQL properly to use the proper column names.

Comment: Thanks! That's more or less what I thought it would come down to. It was more of a curiosity than a desire to use in something :)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind selecting from V_User instead of User, then views can get you what you need.

```
CREATE VIEW V_User AS
SELECT username as username,
       username as uname
FROM User;
```

Then these 2 queries have the same result:

```
mysql> SELECT id, username FROM V_User;
...
mysql> SELECT id, uname FROM V_User;
...
```

As Ken points out, this is not precisely what was asked. But depending on the precise context, it might be just what's needed.

Comment: It also may or may not work, depending on whether or not you need to update/insert and whether the DBMS supports updateable views.

Comment: Indeed. But the request was only for select, so in that context it's potentially useful.