# SQLITE pure permanent column alias

Tags: sqlite

I have a problem similar to 
[Alias Column Names at the Database Level [MySQL]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20435870/alias-column-names-at-the-database-level-mysql)

It was in 2013, may be status as changed in 2015 so I am asking again :)

I got a table with auto generated names for columns that can be a bit long and with '.' and '^' chars in there, the number of columns this way can be high.

This is ok, I can always quote this later in queries.

Ex: select 'a.c.d^e.f' from t

Now for popular request, i.e columns used very often, I'd like to be able to setup an alias name, I fear the answer is NO , yet asking :)

Dreaming about creating an aditional column afterward like this

alter table t alias [column] 'a.c.d^e.f' to F

I could then issue: select F from t; 
Would be short no quote etc...

Thanx in advance
Phi

Comment: How about creating a VIEW with your custom column aliases, while data for columns being selected from table 't'?

Comment: I had the feeling that creating a view require a 'copy' there is a select associated with the view that scare me away because my tables is big (high number of columns in the magniture of 200, and number of raws real big 100K in some case 1M) so I am kind of reluctanct to copy all this.

Comment: *You* might have that feeling, but computers don't have feelings. When in doubt, check with [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html).

Comment: The view does *not* copy any data. It just executes the SELECT query, just like you would do manually.

Comment: Super! That's true that I don't have the 'explain query' reflex as I learn, and sure enough this is the most didactic feature of SQLITE. I'll try to remember that  in the future :) Cheers,